# optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin changes my styles when building

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, internet-explorer-11

My webpack changes my styles when building in prod, I need fix it.

This is for IE11, because  IE11 don't support some property in css.
I know that OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin changes my styles but I don't know how to set it up

I have input style

```css
.selector {
 background-color: transparent;
 border-collapse: separate;
}
```

output

```css
.selector {
 background-color: initial;
 border-collapse: initial;
}
```

my webpack config for OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin

```
 new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
          cssProcessorOptions: {
            parser: safePostCssParser,
            map: shouldUseSourceMap
              ? {
                  inline: false,
                  annotation: true,
                }
              : false,
          },
        })
```

I expect that style doesn't change

Comment: What the webpack and the optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin version you are using? Have you ever tried to use F12 developer tools to check whether the css style is override, then, you could try to use '!important' property.

Comment: i use webpack 4.19.1, optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin 5.0.1
if i use dev build then it is ok, i have only problem on prod build, and '!important' don't help me because webpack rewrites my css styles.